# animated multiple jquery ui dialog box on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have jquery ui dialog box, and I want to Animate multiple dialog boxes on single click.
But it animate only inner boxes div inside the complete dialog box.anyone let me know how to do this ?
I've done this: [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wKcDP/42/)

//Script

```
     $("#animate").click(function() {      

     $('#dialog').animate({
         left: "50px",
            });
     $('#dialog2').animate({
         top: "100px",
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Joe almost had it, but I think the `ui-dialog` selector will animate both of the dialogs when you actually have two different animations.  Try this:

```
$('#dialog').parents(".ui-dialog").animate({
             left: "50px",
                });
$('#dialog2').parents(".ui-dialog").animate({
             top: "100px",
                });

     });
```

That uses the `.parents()` selector method to move the appropriate dialogs.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wKcDP/44/

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help. Be sure to mark the appropriate answer if this solved the question.

Comment: why not, i am appropriating this answer too